# How to move button up, without breaking styling on other pages?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

Recently customized "add to cart" button to look properly alligment via this CSS:

```
.products .product .add_to_cart_button {
display: inline-block;
background: #070bf7 !important;
top:360px;
left:30px;
color:#fff;
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .button {
margin-top:370px;
margin-left:70px;
opacity:1;
}
```

but when go [here](http://touchdowner.cz/digital-products/produkt/artist-website/) button is misalligment.. If place this CSS:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .button {
margin-top: 200px;
margin-left: 70px;
opacity: 1;
}
```

but this CSS breaks my previous modifications. How to apply this CSS only on selected product pages? Here is example [page](http://touchdowner.cz/digital-products/produkt/artist-website/) where issue is visible.

[image]

Comment: We don't generally go to live websites as it means usually trawling through a lot of code. Screenshots are helpful to see the issue but it's better to see your attempt an example of the entire code specific to the problem so we can help you with a specific issue. Saying it does not work "how do you fix it" without any attempt won't get a good response here.

Comment: i writen that i tryed to customize the CSS, but it breakt styling on other pages. i added link to page where issue is visible.

Comment: I've taken a quick look at your website and the element layout it a bit messy. You have a lot of margin-top's pushing everything down where you want it when that is not good code. You should be creating better div structure and hierarchy and you would not need those at all.

Comment: Im searching for concrete sollution. I know that my site is a mess.

Comment: Go to a theme website that uses woocommerce and look at their structure of product elements. That will give you a decent starting point on being able to build your product elements with the css for the correct button positioning. Of course, there is no one way to do it but will give you a good idea to learn from. Obviously take other peoples work with a pinch of salt, as its a good baseline but not always perfect or the way you should do it, that comes with experience.